# How do you remove a word completely from an Apache Solr index?

Tags: solr, stemming

I'm running Apache Solr 6.6.5. When a user searches for "ETCS" (a special technical term) then all documents are matches that contain the word "etc". But I only want to match documents that really contain "ETCS". Solr should never even index "etc" since it is such a common word. The stemmer should never turn "etc" into "etcs" (the plural stemming).

I added "etc" to stopwords.txt:

```
# Contains words which shouldn't be indexed for fulltext fields, e.g., because
# they're too common. For documentation of the format, see
# http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory
# (Lines starting with a pound character # are ignored.)
etc
```

I added "etc" to protwords.txt:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# This file blocks words from being operated on by the stemmer and word delimiter.
&amp;
&lt;
&gt;
&#039;
&quot;
etc
```

That helps to not match documents that contain "etc", but documents containing "etc.", "etc," or similar are still matched.

So I could add even more variants to protwords.txt:

```
&amp;
&lt;
&gt;
&#039;
&quot;
etc
etc.
etc..
etc...
etc,
```

But that will always be incomplete. How can I tell the stemmer to consider "etc" as tokenized word with arbitrary non-word characters around it?

My schema.xml: https://gist.github.com/klausi/f59ee47a9b14b915f5bb44bd6cf1c945

Comment: Which field type in your schema is this? The position of the stopword filter will be what's relevant - i.e. whether it's placed before or after the tokens are processed in the manner expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.)

> I added "etc" to protwords.txt:

you should add `etcs` to protwords to protect stemming of the term `etcs`.

2.)

> So I could add even more variants to protwords.txt:

Add all variations of words you like to remove from the index into the `stopwords.txt`, not the `protwords.txt`

3.) check what filed type you are using. Maybe you can tune that here a bit

//Edit: adding a link to your `schema.xml` will not help as long as you does not explain, which field you are using.

4.) don`t forget to restart and (if needed) reindex your index.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got the meaning of protwords.txt wrong, now putting "etcs" there solved my problem and the behavior is as expected :-)